# Creating a line plot with discontinuities

Tags: r, plot, lines

I want to produce a line plot for a function with some discontinuities. My function has been formed from a simulated brownian motion path as follows:

```
  t <- 1:100
  std <- 0.01
  x <- rnorm(n = length(t) - 1, sd = sqrt(std))
  x <- c(0, cumsum(x))

  #add in some discontinuities

  x[25:35] <- x[25:35] + 0.2
  x[45:55] <- x[45:55] - 0.5
```

My approach has been to set up an empty plot with `plot(0, xlim = c(-49,50), ylim = c(-2, 2))` and then try to add the continuous pieces of the function in steps via

```
  lines((-49):(-25), x[1:25])
  lines((-25):(-15), x[25:35])
  lines((-15):(-5), x[35:45])
  lines((-5):5, x[45:55])
  lines(5:50, x[55:100])
```

The problem is that the resulting plot is continuous. For some reason R is connecting what should be disjoint pieces of the graph. How can I suppress this behavior?

Thanks very much!

Comment: I'd appreciate a comment corresponding to the anonymous downvote. I can fix the question if I don't know what's wrong with it ...

Comment: I suspect the downvote is because your code produces a bunch of errors (for example in `x[25:35] <- x[25:33] + 0.2` you are assigning 9 values to 11 slots, perhaps try to make the indices match...) Ditto with many of your `lines` commands.

Comment: That's fair. I am not at my R console right now and so had to write the question from memory and without the benefit of being able to compile and run to make sure there weren't errors. I've tried to fix the ones you kindly pointed out though. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Again, some of your `lines` commands have errors as your x and y lengths differ (e.g. in `lines((-15):5, x[35:45])`, `-15:5` is 21 elements long whereas `x[35:45]` is 11 elements long, and a few other of your `lines` calls too).

However, your problem is that when you are drawing your lines you are *including* the 'break point' in both `lines` calls.

First, let's construct some simpler data...

```
x <- 1:10
y <- c(1:5, 10:15)
```

Plot the first segment:

```
plot(x[1:5], y[1:5], xlim=range(x), ylim=range(y), type='l') # type='l' draws a line
```

Note that the next segment is `x[6:10]`, **not** `x[5:10]` as you have been doing.

```
lines(x[6:10], y[6:10])
```

And you get:

[image]

So basically when you plot your segments, ensure that they are actually distinct from each other (since `lines` and `plot` plot *inclusive* of the end points):

e.g. instead of:

lines((-49):(-25), x[1:25])
  lines((-25):(-15), x[25:35])

use

lines((-49):(-25), x[1:25])
  lines((-24):(-15), x[26:35]) # <-- remove overlap

and so on.

Comment: Thanks. The reason for the overlap is that I'm looking for right continuous paths, and so the function should go right up to the discontinuity and then have a hole at the left limit. I guess I'll see if a gap of 1 integer is too big and proceed from there ...

Comment: Well my fix isn't pretty, but you certainly identified the problem. Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: If you wanted two lines with a "true" discontinuity, then you need two y values for the *same* x value, e.g. `plot(1:3, rep(-1, 3), xlim=c(1, 5), ylim=c(-1,1)); lines(3:5, rep(1, 3))`. Here your `x` is not 1:5, it's `c(1:3, 3:5)`.